# What's the difference between rt-PCR COVID-19 test using different lengths of nose swab?

Tags: covid-19, test

I [read](https://urgentcarelajolla.com/services/covid-tests-travel/):

> Our nose swabs only enter the nose ½ inch, not all the way up the nostril, ensuring no pain or damage.

A few months ago, I had a COVID-19 test with a nose swabs that looked like ~5cm.

What's the difference between rt-PCR COVID-19 test using different lengths of nose swab? Do they yield the same detection accuracy? Is there any other upside of downsides aside from the length of what is being inserted in one's nose? I searched online but couldn't find a good answer yet.

Comment: I have heard that some places doing a lot of tests (e.g., hospitals) were testing the two types of test to see if they differ in accuracy, although I haven't seen any publications on that.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks interesting! 1 year forward, have you seen any publications on that by any chance?